# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myselect' of undefined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript

I have a select box element with id `myselect`.  The select box is in a form called `myform`.  I am sure it is in this form because printing this before where my error is happening prints the correct form:

```
>> console.log(document.forms[0].id);
   myform
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myselect' of undefined (anonymous function)
```

where I do this:

```
document.myform.myselect
```

Any ideas why?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the form as a property of `document.forms`, not `document`:

```
document.forms.myform.myselect
```

You can avoid falling into the traps of implied globals and properties in the future by just using `document.getElementById()`:

```
document.getElementById("myform").myselect;
document.getElementById("myselect");
```